# Differences between PAM and Metis partitioning

Tags: graph, social-networking, cluster-analysis, partitioning

Is Partitioning Around Medoids (PAM; a robust version of k-means) much different than METIS partitioning of matrices? I mean of course they are different methods, but will the output be substantially different?

I don't know Metis, just know that it is a partitioning method for matrices.  If one applied PAM and Metis to distance matrix, how different would the results be?

Background: I read a working paper that used Metis to partition a sociomatrix (an nxn matrix of who is friends with whom).  Since Metis is not implemented in R, I want to roughly get at their results using PAM.

Thoughts?  Any references would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have some references?

> METIS is a set of serial programs for partitioning graphs, partitioning finite element meshes, and producing fill reducing orderings for sparse matrices. The algorithms implemented in METIS are based on the multilevel recursive-bisection, multilevel k-way, and multi-constraint partitioning schemes developed in our lab.

Does not sound as if METIS would be a **single algorithm**, so I figure your question does is not well formed. Maybe you first should research Metis more yourself (or give us some more reference what method you *exactly* are referring to).

Comment: Thanks - sorry it's my first question post, so a bit of work in progress.
From the manual [link](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/fetch/sw/metis/manual.pdf) it suggests that metis implements algorithms that involve 3 steps: coarsen, partition, then uncoarsen a graph.  so, the output is graph partition.  i just don't see how it would be different. original paper here [link](http://epubs.siam.org.ezp-prod1.hul.harvard.edu/doi/abs/10.1137/S1064827595287997)